Updating text on the UI Thread every 40ms in a MAUI app
I'm working on a MAUI Application which needs to update a label in the UI every 40ms (it's displaying a real-time SMPTE Timecode). What's the best way to achieve this without a ridiculous amount of CPU Usage? I've tried running a separate thread which retrieves the updated text every 40ms, and invokes an event on the main UI Thread:
Task.Run(async () =>{
        while(true){
            Thread.Sleep(40);
            var str = GetNewText();
            OnNewTimecode?.Invoke(this, new NewTimecodeEventArgs() { Timecode = str });
        }
    });

MainPage.xaml.cs:
    listener.OnNewTimecode += (sender, args) =>
        {
        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            TimecodeDisplay.Text = args.Timecode;
        });
    };

However passing data across threads via events like that seems to increase CPU Usage very significantly.
I'm thinking it would probably be better for performance to just have a variable that's shared across threads, and that the UI Thread directly retrieves and displays every 40ms, but I'm unsure how to achieve this without blocking everything else.

Are you sure that the CPU spike is caused by the inter-thread communication, and not by either the mere act of updating the text of the label, or by whatever happens inside the GetNewText method?

It's not GetNewText(), because commenting out OnNewTimecode?.Invoke() so there's no inter-thread communication reduces the usage down to around 1-2%. If I don't update the text, it hovers around 6% usage, which isn't as bad as the 30%, but still feels like a lot of overhead. So I feel like it might be a combination of updating the text of the label along with the inter-thread communication?

Have you tried just relying on data binding?

I would suggest to try updating the label with a random text once every 40 msec using an UI timer, and see if the same CPU spike emerges. My expectation is that the overhead of the inter-thread communication is minuscule. I would be surprised if it's proven to be the cause of the spike.

Maui appears to be very sensitive when it comes to callbacks on the UI thread. You could try to use a synchronous callback (Invoke instead of BeginInvoke) or use the dispatcher instead of the thread object for the callback.

Would this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73816335/device-starttimer-is-deprecated-in-maui-what-is-the-alternative/73917792#73917792


I'm thinking it would probably be better for performance to just have a variable that's shared across threads, and that the UI Thread directly retrieves and displays every 40ms, but I'm unsure how to achieve this without blocking everything else.

Sharing variables across threads is most likely not the issue here. The example is essentially creating an object and posting a reference of this object to the UI threads event queue. While this will involve some kind of synchronization, in the  latency numbers every programmer should know we can see that a lock takes about 25ns.
The real code will take much longer since it involves creating multiple objects and some other code, but I would still guess on the order of single or double digit microseconds.
The actual rendering of the UI will likely take milliseconds, i.e. several magnitudes more. So I would find your theory that it is the actual sharing that takes time unlikely, and some kind of shared variable will likely not help.
If you want to know what actually takes time, use a performance profiler. This way you do not have to guess about where the CPU time goes. And it is notoriously difficult to make guesses about performance, so it is worth the effort in learning how to use a profiler if you have any performance concerns at all.
The typical solution for doing anything periodically is to use a timer. There are several kinds, but you probably want one that raises the 'Tick' event on the UI thread. I have not used MAUI, but it seems like Dispatcher.CreateTimer is the way to create a UI timer. This is assuming GetNewTextis suitable for running on the UI thread. If it takes a significant time to run for any reason, say 10ms or so,  you may need to consider alternative solutions. But it becomes more difficult to provide recommendations without knowing the specific requirements and limitations.

The problem with all event-based timers (excluding the PeriodicTimer which is not event-based) is that they allow overlapping executions of the event handler. The approach used by the OP, a loop with an embedded delay, doesn't suffer form this problem, so it's arguably better than a timer.

@TheodorZoulias I cannot really see how any timer that raises events on the UI thread could suffer from concurrent executions. It could possibly queue multiple events, I can't see anything in the documentation if DispatchTimer coalesces events or not. This is assuming GetNewText can/should run on the UI thread.

Jonas an event handler can be asynchronous (async void), and invoke asynchronous I/O methods or offload CPU-bound methods to the ThreadPool. In which case concurrency can happen very easily, depending on the duration of the work and the interval of the UI timer.

@TheodorZoulias Sure, but I do not see how it is relevant to the question, GetNewText seem very synchronous to me. Granted, if you write threaded or asynchronous code you need to pay attention to thread safety and ordering, but that is true regardless if you are using a timer or not.

Jonas the GetNewText is synchronous, but the OP is invoking it on the ThreadPool. So if they switched their approach to a timer, according to your suggestion, then they would probably want to continue invoking it on the ThreadPool. So they would make the hander async and do var str = await Task.Run(() => GetNewText());. Do you have any valid reason to believe that invoking the GetNewText on the UI thread would do any good to the OP?

@TheodorZoulias As I mentioned in a previous comment, I'm assuming GetNewText  can run on the UI thread, and that the run-while-sleep is just used due to not knowing about timers. I also assume "retrieves the updated text" means the information is already available in memory and is fairly cheap to get. If it means the data needs to be fetched over IO then a periodic timer with async IO would indeed be much more suitable.

Jonas it would be fairly atypical if a programmer has knowledge of threading and asynchronous programming, and he/she is not aware about timers!
